# Django - forloop to show/filter a value to show only once the entrys

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I have a model (Restrictie) in which those who voted (participanti) and those who voted (votant) are registered. If I forloop in the templates, I can see who voted for whom, but one line is displayed for each record. How can I make a forloop or query in which participants are displayed only once and next to all the voters for example:

**name participanti - (name votant 1, name votant 2, ....)**

Below my code

models.py

```
class Participanti(models.Model):
    campanievot = models.ForeignKey(Campanie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nume_participant = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='nume')
    dep_participant = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='departament')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nume_participant

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Participanti'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Participanti'


class Restrictie(models.Model):

    participanti = models.ForeignKey(Participanti,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Votat')
    votant = models.ForeignKey(UserVot,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.participanti)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Voturi efectuate'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Voturi efectuate'
```

views.py

```
def rezultate(request):
    
    cineavotat = Restrictie.objects.all()
.......
```

I tried this but it's show all entries like : **name 1** = voters 1, **name 1** = voters 2 ...

```
{% for p in cineavotat %}  
 
  {{ p.participanti }} - {{ p.votant}}
  
{% endfor %}
```

Please help me with a solution. Thank you!

Comment: It seems you should reassess your modeling, possibly making Vote an entity itself to have more flexibility (could be a through model between a Restrictie and Users). It also seems Participanti numbers can be deducted from such a model and only adds persistency/optimization in your data model.

Answer (score 0):

In Views.py

```
def rezultate(request):
    cineavotat = Restrictie.objects.all()
    context = {'cineavotat': cineavotat}
    return render(request, 'appname/templatename.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,  but i have the view seta like your exemple (i put .... becauze i this the rest of the code is irrelevat for my question). The problem is in for loop a get all the entrys, line by line, and it;s repet the "particpianti" value for each "votant" that has a record. What i want is to know how to list the "participanti" value only once and all the "votant" record in the same line like this: for ex i have "robert" as the "participanti" record and robert has been voted by votant : sam, angela,..; so, in template i want to have display like this : robert - (sam, angela,.).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/
so here you can find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you better to select a list of Participanti and for each of them add list of Restrictie in your view, like this:

```
def rezultate(request):
    cineavotat = []
    for p in Participanti.objects.all():
        cineavotat.append((p, p.restrictie_set.all()))
    return render(request, 'appname/templatename.html', {'cineavotat': cineavotat})
```

And then you could do this in your template

```
{% for participanti, restrictie in cineavotat %}  

  {{ participanti }} -
  {% for r in restrictie  %} 
    {{r.votant}};
  {% endfor %}  
  </br>

{% endfor %}
```

The result is

```
Some Participanti - User 1; User 2; User 3;
Another Participanti - User 2; User 3;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what i wanted. It' work. In this case shows all the participanti but in template i put 

{% if participanti.votes == 0 %}  

{% else %}
  {{ participanti }} -
  {% for r in restrictie  %} 
    {{r.votant}}; 
  {% endfor %} <br> 
{% endif %}

and now a see only the participants that receive a minimum 1 vote

Thank you!!!

Comment: @RobertMurariu you can also do this with filters. Just replace Participanti.objects.all() with Participanti.objects.filter(votes__gt=0) in the view. This can simplify your template.

Comment: Yes. It's work also with Participanti.objects.filter(votes__gt=0). Thank you very much.